# Auto deploy docker images on push

Tags: docker, github, ansible, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

First, I'm noob with Continuous Deployement. I currently have a VPS running 3 docker containers (Flask, MongoDb, Nginx) that I'm pulling from DockerHub with a docker-compose. What I want to do is auto deploy those 3 containers when pushing some code in my github repo. I think It's possible with Ansible but I never used it.

Someone can explain me how to do it ?
Many thx !

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for webhooks. Docker hub can send a post to some service endpoint on your VPS that triggers a pull/up.

Comment: @mathis Any idea what Github Actions are? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images

Comment: Finally I will use Jenkins :)

Comment: @phd this is only for publish on DockerHub not for auto deploy on VPS

Answer (score 0):

> Finally I will use Jenkins :)

That implies a webhook, as explained in "[How to Integrate Your GitHub Repository to Your Jenkins Project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project)" by **[Guy Salton](https://github.com/guysalton-codefresh)**

[image: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/208250/Blog_Images/jengit3.png]

And that means your Jenkins server is accessible through an internet-facing public URL, which is not always obvious when working in a corporate environment.

GitHub Actions "[Publishing Docker images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images)" can help publishing the image to DockerHub, but you still need to listen/detect those events in order for your Jenkins to trigger job pulling said ppublished images.

For that, a regular sheduler Jenkins job using [**`regclient/regclient`**](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) can help checking the latest published SHA2 image ID has or has not changed.
See more with "[Container Registry Management with Brandon Mitchell: DevOps and Docker (Ep 108)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=es1eC-fMHkI&t=218s)".